# webdriverio 5 for unit testing and functional testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, functional-testing, webdriver-io

I have a  project that is written using node and webpack.

I am writing tests for the application and as the output of my application is a visualization, I went with webdriverio 5 and it is running great(functional testing). However when I add unit tests, it is just failing although in the test reporter it shows that it is false, the logs tell that it FAILED.

Here is how my package.json file looks like

```
{
  "name": "webdriverio-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app/index.js",
  "scripts": {
"install-selenium": "./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install",
"start-selenium": "./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start",
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js",
"allure-report": "allure generate allure-results --clean && allure open"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^5.12.1",
    "@wdio/cli": "^5.12.5",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.12.5",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^5.12.1",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^5.12.1",
    "@wdio/sync": "^5.12.3"
     }
    }
```

Here is how my test file looks like

```
const assert = require('assert'); 
const index = require('../../app/index').default 

describe('test browser', function () { 
    it('should have the right title', function ()  { 
        browser.url('https://webdriver.io'); 
        const title = browser.getTitle(); 
        //assert.strictEqual(title, 'WebdriverIO · Next-gen WebDriver test framework for Node.js'); 
        console.log("**********I am here*************"); 
        assert.equal(5,5); 
    }); 
}); 


describe('test code', function () { 
    it('should have do the right thing', function ()  { 
        const c = index.add(3,4); 
        assert.equal(c, 7); 
    }); 
});
```

When I run this code using webdriverio command I get the following stack trace

```
> webdriverio-test@1.0.0 test /Users/adsf/Desktop/test_scripts/webdriverio-test
> wdio wdio.conf.js


Execution of 1 spec files started at 2019-09-06T15:21:35.952Z

2019-09-06T15:21:35.979Z INFO @wdio/cli:Launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2019-09-06T15:21:36.093Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: Could not request headers from       https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/chromedriver_mac64.zip: Error: read ECONNRESET
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/adsf/Desktop/test_scripts/webdriverio-test/node_modules/selenium-standalone/lib/install.js:552:8)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at Request.onRequestError (/Users/adsf/Desktop/test_scripts/webdriverio-test/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)

Continue...
2019-09-06T15:21:36.096Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: wdio.conf.js
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - /test/specs/basic.js
[0-0] 2019-09-06T15:21:36.381Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] 2019-09-06T15:21:36.434Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session
[0-0] 2019-09-06T15:21:36.434Z INFO webdriver: DATA { capabilities:
   { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome' }, firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } }
[0-0] 2019-09-06T15:21:37.385Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND navigateTo("https://webdriver.io/")
[0-0] 2019-09-06T15:21:37.386Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/3e34d38c50817313e3bab65cf8af5e51/url
[0-0] 2019-09-06T15:21:37.386Z INFO webdriver: DATA { url: 'https://webdriver.io/' }
[0-0] 2019-09-06T15:21:38.901Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND getTitle()
[0-0] 2019-09-06T15:21:38.901Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/3e34d38c50817313e3bab65cf8af5e51/title
[0-0] 2019-09-06T15:21:38.908Z INFO webdriver: RESULT WebdriverIO · Next-gen WebDriver test framework for Node.js
[0-0] **********I am here*************
[0-0] FAILED in chrome - /test/specs/basic.js
2019-09-06T15:21:39.335Z INFO @wdio/cli:Launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:03 

2019-09-06T15:21:39.336Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2019-09-06T15:21:39.590Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2019-09-06T15:21:39.590Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webdriverio-test@1.0.0 test: `wdio wdio.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webdriverio-test@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

My question is can I run unit tests and functional tests with wdio or will it be a good idea for me to use mocha and wdio to run these tests?

When I just run browser tests, all the browser tests work great

Comment: It is showing failed as there is a failure in your onPrepare hook, please check your services in config file

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is not a good idea to run different types of tests in one file( since only the first describe will work - for your example) and the logs will be written according to the wdio settings.I ran your example in different files and it worked correctly - 2 passed
 It is better to move the UI tests to the same folder with package.json settings for Wdio, and Unit-tests with mocha to another separate folder.